# Multiline prompt with ansi-term

Tags: ansi-term

Running plain Emacs with `emacs -Q` then running `ansi-term`, if I input some long text in the prompt such that the text breaks into the next line (without hitting Return), then I hit <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> to create another frame, for some reason the prompt is half repeated.

Is there a way to fix this?

In my actual setup, I use `zsh` with a multiline prompt, so that everytime I invoke a command that creates a temporary frame, like `helm-mini`, the prompt is repeated creating a mess out of my terminal.

Comment: I can confirm this on Emacs 27.0.50. No idea why it happens or how to fix it though :/